# Chat system in Java

Tags: java, client-server

Is there a way to immediately print the message received from the client without using an infinite loop to check whether the input stream is empty or not?
Because I found that using infinite loop consumes a lot of system resources, which makes the program running so slow. And we also have to do the same (infinite loop) on the client side to print the message on the screen in real time.
I'm using Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be dealing with the input stream in a separate [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) - and let it [block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) waiting for input. It will not use any resources while it blocks. If you're seeing excessive resource usage while doing this sort of thing, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Oh yeah, I found the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just put your loop in a different thread and have it sleep a bit (maybe for half a second?) between iterations. It would still be an infinite loop, but it would not consume nearly as many resources.

Comment: OK, I'll try it. I'm wondering how the real chatting software works. It doesn't seem to consume resource at all.

Comment: That really depends on what you mean by "real". There are *many* different approaches to writing servers like this, so chances are different servers deal with it differently.

Comment: Using sleep just makes the chat server less responsive without really addressing the problem.

Comment: Won't it not consume nearly as many resources if it pauses a bit between each iteration? I imagine there are better approaches, like @millhouse suggested, but I think mine would reduce the amount of resources consumed.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis - it does reduce resource usage, but 1) you are still wasting resources by polling every 0.5 seconds (or whatever) and 2) the 0.5 second delay on responding makes the server feel sluggish.

Comment: using a `Socket`'s input stream, you can `.readUTF()` to block until data is received. Put that in a thread, like you said to do, and that eliminates the need to loop. It's how I always process data like this.

Comment: Yeah, that makes more sense than just looping.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches that avoid busy loops / sleeps.

- Use a thread for each client connection, and simply have each thread call `read`.  This blocks the thread until the client sends some data, but that's no problem because it doesn't block the threads handling other clients.
- Use Java NIO channel selectors.  These allow a thread to wait until one of set of channels (in this case sockets) has data to be read.  There is a section of the [Oracle Java Tutorials](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0320__Network/Channelselector.htm) on this.

Of these two approaches, the second one is most efficient in terms of overall resource usage.  (The thread-per-client approach uses a lot of memory on thread stacks, and CPU on thread switching overheads.)

---

Busy loops that repeatedly call (say) `InputStream.available()` to see if there is any input are horribly inefficient.  You can make them less inefficient by slowing down the polling with `Thread.sleep(...)` calls, but this has the side effect of making the service less responsive.  For instance, if you add a 1 second sleep between each set of polls, the effect that each client will see is that the server *typically* delays 1 second before processing each request.  Assuming that those requests are keystrokes and the responses echo them, the net result is a horribly laggy service.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I was using InputStream.available(), and I fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't you change your architecture a little bit to accommodate `WebSockets`. check out [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) . It is a cross browser WebSockets enabler.

You will have to write controllers *(servlets for example in java)* that push data to the client. This does not follow the request-response architecture.

You can also architect it so that a "push servlet" triggers a "request" from the client to obtain the "response".

Since your question talks about Java, and if you are interested in WebSockets, check this [link](http://jwebsocket.org/) out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Sockets`, which you should be for any networking.

Then you can use the socket's `DataInputStream` which you can get using `socket.getInputStream()` (i think that's the right method) and do the following:

```
public DataInputStream streamIn;
public Socket soc;

// initialize socket, etc...
    streamIn = soc.getInputStream();

public String getInput() {
    return (String) streamIn.readUTF(); // Do some other casting if this doesn't work
}
```

`streamIn.readUTF()` blocks until data is available, meaning you don't have to loop, and threading will let you do other processing while you wait for data.

Look here for more information on `DataInputStream` and what you can do with it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html

Answer (score 0):

A method that does not require threads would involve subclassing the input stream and adding a notify type method. When called this method would alert any interested objects (i.e. objects that would have to change state due to the additions to the stream) that changes have been made. These interested objects could then respond in anyway that is desired.

Objects writing to the buffer would do their normal writing, and afterward would call the notify() method on the input stream, informing all interested objects of the change.

Edit: This might require subclassing more than a couple of classes and so could involve a lot of code changes. Without knowing more about your design you would have to decide if the implementation is worth the effort.